# Are PostgreSQL temporary tables already unlogged?

Tags: database, postgresql, optimization

I am working on a database operation, which produces a lot of inserts (~ 15,000,000).

I am currently using a temporary table for this data, because the data is no longer required after the operation. I recently found out, that unlogged tables have a better insert performance and hence I want to use it. But reading the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtable.html), it is not clear to me if temporary tables are already unlogged? And if they are not, is there a way to make them unlogged?

If I try to alter a temporary table like this:

```sql
alter table temp_table set unlogged;
```

I get the error: `[42P16] ERROR: cannot change logged status of table "test" because it is temporary`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Temporary tables are never WAL logged.

Since they will be gone with the database session, there is never a need to recover them.

Comment: I was doing `create temp unlogged table` and getting error msg `syntax error at or near "unlogged"`. This saved my day.